# How to localize plupload plugin jquery

Tags: plupload

**How to localize plupload**
I have the language scripts but i have no ide hot to make plupload work in my language

I tried to include the localization file but it didnet work

i dont want to change the text directly in plugin

Comment: can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1):

To activate the language pack you simply need to include the corresponding js file after the Plupload scripts, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js"></script>

<!-- activate Slovak translation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/i18n/sk.js"></script>
```

https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/wiki/Plupload-in-Your-Language